# is this a closure in JavaScript as Im not sure?

Tags: javascript

Is this a  closure in JavaScript?

```
var test = function(b){
    var a = 1;
    return function(b){
        a + b
    }
};
var c = test(2);
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Yes, the returned function is a closure. It's kind-of strange, because the parameter to the "test" function isn't used.

Comment: As @Pointy mentioned, this will **not** return `3`. This will return the anonymous function `function(b) { a + b }` (which doesn't actually do anything, as it doesn't return anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure is introduced then you define a function within test that returns local properties of the test function. an example of a closure would be here:

```
;(function() {

    var local = 123

    window.foo = function() {
        return local
    }
})()
```

What you're pretty close to in your example is currying, which involves a function that returns a function to take a second parameter. e.g:

```
function add(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

add(5)(6) // 11
```

Answer (score 0):

var a; and parameter b of the outer function are part  of the closure of the inner function. For detailed explanation of closures have a look in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

```
var test = function(b){ // <= param b is part of the closure of the inner function
    var a = 1;          // <= a is part of the closure of the inner function as well 
    return function(b){ // <= the inner function
        a + b           // <= here you are just add ind a and b together
                        //    return a + b; //would be more appropriate
    }
};
var c = test(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var globalVar = "xyz";

(function outerFunc(outerArg) {
    var outerVar = 'a';
    
    (function innerFunc(innerArg) {
    var innerVar = 'b';
    
    console.log(
        "outerArg = " + outerArg + "\n" +
        "innerArg = " + innerArg + "\n" +
        "outerVar = " + outerVar + "\n" +
        "innerVar = " + innerVar + "\n" +
        "globalVar = " + globalVar);
    
    })(456);
})(123);
```

**this code is same to above code but is new way of writing result and output will be same**
 *})(123);* here firstly automatically call outer function pass argument 123 then 
*})(456);* call inner function automatically

Note in this way no return require

Comment: Whenever we use function inside another function, a closure is used.
means A closure is basically when an inner function has access to variables outside of its scope

Answer (score 0):

```js
var globalVar = "xyz";

function outerFunc(outerArg) {
    var outerVar = 'a';
    
     var r3= function innerFunc(innerArg) {
    var innerVar = 'b';
    
    console.log(
        "outerArg = " + outerArg + "\n" +
        "innerArg = " + innerArg + "\n" +
        "outerVar = " + outerVar + "\n" +
        "innerVar = " + innerVar + "\n" +
        "globalVar = " + globalVar);
    
    };
 return r3;
};

var r=outerFunc(123);
r(456);
```

**var r=outerFunc(123); ...here we have called outer-function and assign this result return in r variable** 
we cannot use inner function directly. we have to call outer function and assign their return in varible
because above code return function

Comment: above code we can also write this simple way old format
we have use inner and outer function 
inner function we have pass in a variable var r3
which is call when out-function call then as return of outer function is inner function